# Is it bad that the root folder directory is being assigned to the web root (public_html) folder instead of its own domain folder within the web root?

Tags: wordpress, performance, cpanel, http-status-code-503

The current site I'm working on gets random inconsistent 503 errors and just crashes for the next few minutes. Noticed that in the file manager instead of there being a folder for the domain itself, it is just dumped directly into the webroot folder, the public_html. Could this be an issue or at least part of the issue?

Answer (score 0):

That is not uncommon. This could be caused by things like lack of memory, storage space or even the server/site getting overloaded with requests.

I would try increasing memory on WordPress first and checking storage space. As well, if you can see the server logs they may give you a direct answer to the cause.